# No Next / Prev Button on jQuery colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm using jQuery colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example3/) on my website.
And I'm trying to add multiple iframe box. It's working except there is no NEXT/PREV button in it.

Here is my code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#group1').colorbox({
        arrowKey: true,
        open: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
        iframe: true,
        innerWidth:1000,  
        innerHeight:600,
        scrolling:false,
        rel:"group1"
        }); 
});
</script>

<a id="group1" href="http://tokobagus.com">Tokobagus</a>
<a id="group1" href="http://berniaga.com">Kaskus</a>
```

As you can see, there's arrowKey: true there, but the arrow is still not showing. Any idea?

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `id` is unique, try to change it to class for both of your anchors:

```
<a class="group1" href="http://tokobagus.com">Tokobagus</a>
<a class="group1" href="http://berniaga.com">Kaskus</a>
```

and use `$('.group1')` instead of `$('#group1')`

Comment: Thanks, it works! will accept as answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Just You have to use `class` instead of `id`. check the solution in

```
http://jsfiddle.net/2kda6/
```